# Google API - how to login with username and password hardcoded?

Tags: php, google-api

I have a mobile app where people uploads image. I don't have enough space on my server to store all the images.. I was thinking to store all the images on google drive. Wanted to check.. how can I login to google api with hardcoded username and password ? I cannot use oAuth as user's will not input the username and passwords. My backend is in PHP.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What about solutions like Amazon's S3 - it is actually made for stuff like this...

Comment: If you really enjoy Google, there is a solution called Google Cloud Storage, which is made for this too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Logging in with a login and password is called client login.  April 2015 Google shut down client login servers.  You cant access any of the Google APIs with a login and password you must use Open authentication.

I suggest you consider using a [service account](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php). A service account is a dummy sudo user it has its own drive account and you can login and upload files to it directly though the API.

Comment: To my understanding they just changed the authentication protocol... it's seems weird that a useful functionality will be missing.